# How do i wrap my script in a $( document ).ready(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help with wrapping my code in a `ready` function. Below is my code:

```
var color = "White";
$("#btnBlue").hover(function () { color = "Blue" });
$("#btnGreen").click(function () { color = "Green" });
$("#btnYellow").click(function () { color = "Yellow" });
$("table tr td").click(function () { $(this).css("background-color", color); });
```

I want to wrap the code into the function below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// Your code here.

});
```

I greatly appreciate any help you can give.

Comment: What's exaclty the question? Why you don't simply place your code inside the document ready function?

Comment: What stopped you from wrapping it in `$( document ).ready(function(){` ?

Comment: just copy-paste your code to  "// Your code here." :)

Comment: You can just move it inside of the function, between the `{}`. A function is just a block of code between `{}`

Comment: Ooops :-). I'll try it out... I am very new to this. Thanks everyone :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var color = "White";
$("#btnBlue").hover(function () { color = "Blue" });
$("#btnGreen").click(function () { color = "Green" });
$("#btnYellow").click(function () { color = "Yellow" });
$("table tr td").click(function () { $(this).css("background-color", color); });

});
```